# JSON para aplicación de wallpapers

Tags: android, json

Bue día, estoy haciendo una aplicación de wallpapers, en si ya esta echa, la aplicación utiliza un archivo JSON el cual debe de estar almacenado en algún servidor y  en el que que tanbien viene la direcciones de los wallpapes y de las previews de los mismos, en este caso el proyecto que uso lo conseguí de GitHub y este es el archivo JSON el cual esta almacenado en el servidor del creador del proyecto que estoy utilizando:
[Archivo JSON](https://jahirfiquitiva.me/frames/wallpapers.json)

Y al abrir el archivo se pueden dar cuenta de que los wallpapers están almacenados en servidores de GitHub

```
{
    "name":"Wallsplash 7",
    "author":"wallsplash",
    "url":"https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/Website-Resources/raw/master/wallpapers/unsplash_g.png",
    "thumbnail":"https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/Website-Resources/raw/master/wallpapers/thumbnails/unsplash_g.png",
    "dimensions":"3200x2560",
    "copyright":"Free (do whatever you want)",
    "collections":"landscapes,people"
},
```

Dicho todo esto lo que quiero saber es en donde puedo almacenar yo mi propio archivo JSON y en donde puedo alojar también mis propias imágenes (wallpapers) espero haber sido lo mas claro posible , gracias adelantadas.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque l tema de la pregunta es hosting, no programación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes adquirir el servicio de algun provedor de hosting como el de hostinger, 1and1,etc.
Una vez hecho esto tendras que crear tus o tu archivo json de respuesta, y tambien tendras que alojar las imagenes de la manera que quieras administrarlas.
Espero haber podido resolver tu duda.

Comment: gracias, imaginava eso, pero no sabes si hay algun servicio gratis??

Comment: a ver revisa esta https://mex.000webhost.com/

Comment: gracias arthur, creo que si me servira